# Confusion over Mathematica 9.0, when calculating the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Why in Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 I get $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1 }\dfrac{1+ \sqrt[5]{x}}{1+ \sqrt[3]{x}}=\frac{1+\sqrt[5]{-1}}{1+\sqrt[3]
   {-1}}$.
 But, my solution is: 1.
Thanks.

Comment: $\sqrt[5]{}$ and $\sqrt[3]{}$ are ambiguous if you are working over the complex numbers, which Mathematica almost certainly does by default. There should be a way to force it to keep everything real, though.

Comment: @Ian To do that, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8

Comment: How looks the command to get the correct result in R?

Comment: Mathematica has some idiosyncratic defaults with its root functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the correct answer is $\;1\;$. Using $\;x^n+1=(x+1)(x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+\ldots-x+1)\;$ for odd $\;n\;$

$$\frac{1+\sqrt[5]x}{1+\sqrt[3]x}=\frac{x^{2/3}-x^{1/3}+1}{x^{4/5}-x^{3/5}+x^{2/5}-x^{1/5}+1}\xrightarrow[x\to-1]{}\frac35$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also use L'Hopital's rule explicitly, here, because both the numerator and denominator approach zero, and their derivatives exist. Hence:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1 }\dfrac{1+ \sqrt[5]{x}}{1+ \sqrt[3]{x}}=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1} \frac{\frac{1}{5}x^{-\frac{4}{5}}}{\frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}}=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -1} \frac{3}{5} x^{-\frac{2}{15}}=\frac{3}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

With L'Hôpital's rule $$\lim _{ x\to -1 }{ \frac { 1+\sqrt [ 5 ]{ x }  }{ 1+\sqrt [ 3 ]{ x }  }  } =\lim _{ x\to -1 }{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ 5\sqrt [ 5 ]{ { x }^{ 4 } }  }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ 3\sqrt [ 3 ]{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  } =\frac { 3 }{ 5 }  }  $$